# mediawiki Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required after server moved

Tags: php, mediawiki

When I moved MediaWiki from Localhost to the server I started getting the below error. I am using the latest version and tried to use php 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 but error exists for all version of php. I know this might not be php version related but just cross checked.

> Warning:
> require_once(/home/meuser/public_html/site_dir\extensions\Cite\Cite.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/meuser/public_html/site_dir/LocalSettings.php on line 132
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/meuser/public_html/site_dir\extensions\Cite\Cite.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in
> /home/meuser/public_html/site_dir/LocalSettings.php on line 132

When I commented Cite extension (to disable the extension) to cross check, it gives the same error for the next extension. So I believe there is something wrong in moving server?

I have just uploaded all files to the server and changed database and site url settings in Localsettings.php and imported database.

Is there any extra step required?

Comment: HAve you checked whether the files are present in the place where the error says they're missing? If they ARE missing... that's your problem...

Comment: On a sidenote, how come half your slashes are forward and the other half backward? Have you switched from a windows to a unix host? And not updated the paths in your configuration file accordingly ?

Comment: Yes all files are presents at the place. I have just zipped and move to the server.

Comment: I don't mean do you *think* they *should* be there, but *are* they there? Have you checked that the exact file mentioned in the error is in the exact place that it should be ?

Comment: @Tularis Yes you are right. I was working on `xampp` windows and server is `linux` `Centos` So where to see this path?

Comment: @Tularis wonderful catch.... you have just solved my problem... all extension was having `\\` instead of `/` the reason is I have installed fresh copy on `XAMPP` Windows.. So I guess system has created that automatically. This is I call experienced eyes :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with the directory separators in your paths. Notice how they're all forward slashes until you reach site_dir. Fix these and it should work perfectly. Based on this code the paths you need to change are in LocalSettings.php

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

Syntax:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./your file location with only '/' slash);
```

ie.,

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./site_dir/extensions/Cite/Cite.php);
```